# Google Sinhalese installation failed

Tags: wine, internationalization

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 3 days ago an have never used it before. I wanted to install an IME for Sinhala so I tried installing Google Sinhalese input via wine following the instructions from the [community documentation on wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine). At the last step the following error message appeared:

1. "Google installation failed with error 0x80040154"
2. "The installer could not connect to the internet.Ensure that your computer is   connected to the internet and your firewall allows GoogleUpdate.exe to connect then try again".

My computer was connected to the internet, and I have no idea of firewall settings on Ubuntu, please guide me. Thanks in advance. If it is connected to firewall settings, be kind to advice me how to change the settings. Thanks.

Also let me know if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu actually has an IME for Sinhala, you just need to add it via system settings -> keyboard layout.

There is also a [translation team on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-si) that would be glad to welcome new members and could give you better advice on related issues.

[image: sinhala in Ubuntu]

**On that wine issue**

You got an error message from a windows application by using wine. Windows applications are generally unaware that they are running on wine and will assume they are running on windows and like in that case will make false assumptions for workarounds and solutions.

The default configuration of Ubuntu has two firewalls. The kernel firewall named Netfilter, which is not configured to filter anything by default as far as I know, and Apparmor an application based firewall which shouldn't get in the way of wine applications.

What zetah referred to was the [appdb on the WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/) site, where a compatibility list of applications is maintained. Unfortunately you can't find "Google Sinhalese" there or variations there of. But what you can find is a [reference to a similar error message of another application using the Google Updater](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21166). Searching for other Google applications, [Google Music Manager seems to work](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23566&iTestingId=63938), but trying to reproduce that with the Sinhalese IME installer in my VM did not work. [Filehippo has offline installers for Chrome](http://www.filehippo.com/de/download_google_chrome/), but does not seem to have for the IME.

Sorry but without more investigation, you would not be able to install that application. Note: We are just talking about a file that needs to be fetched from a server, that's all there is, the rest of the installation process would run fine. It is a nuisance, but Google still insists on using this malware like installation process for their Windows software. They have been doing so or years.

Comment: 1. Thanks so much for your understanding and kindness.

Comment: Thanks so much,Sir for your understanding and kindness.It,s a good news for me to know about "translation team on launchpad". I didn't know about them. I appreciate your encouraging words and I got all what you explained. A big thanks to you sir, for helping me.

Comment: As you said Sir,I couldn't install Google sinhala input IME.What happens in Google sinhalese IME is,if I type any Sinhalese word as it sounds using Roman key board that same word gets typed in Sinhalese automatically.But it is not true with phonetic key board,which is the standard Sinhalese keyboard. It is hard to remember the keys in that key board and take more time in typing......GOOD NEWS.....I got another method from, http://sinhala.sourceforge.net/ it is very much similar to Google IME.Very easy to install for beginners.I installed that for Ubuntu 12.04.Thank You very much.